# Transitive and Intransitive verbs (run)

Tags: verbs

An *intransitive* verb is a verb that denotes an action which does not pass over to an object or which expresses a state or being

> He ran **a long distance.**

According to me here **run** is a *transitive* verb because it has its object **a long distance**. But in my grammar book it is said to be intransitive. I am confused over this.

Comment: Some people do take it as intransitive with "a long distance" as a spatial adjunct. But I think the transitive analysis is better, where "a long distance" is Od of "ran".

Answer (score 1):

Notice that **run** can be both transitive and intransitive with the same meaning.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**run**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run) **[ I or T ]**

> (of people and some animals) to move along, faster than walking, by
>   taking quick steps in which each foot is lifted before the next foot
>   touches the ground

[I or T] meaning [Intransitive or Transitive]

When can check another source to gather additional information.

According to the Oxford Learners Dictionary

[**run**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/run_1) **[transitive]**

> run **something** to travel a particular distance by running 
> *Who was the
>   first person to run **a mile** in under four minutes?*